# Nested for loop php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, nested

So I'm creating this php local site for my work 
it is about mortgage
and I made this code as a begging

```
<?php 
$income=1650;
$rate=7;
$period=240;
$graduation =60;
$paytoinc=40;
$rowage=7;
for ($l=1; $l <= $period ; $l++) { 
    for ($i=1; $i <= $graduation ; $i=+12) { 
        $NPV = (1/pow(1+($rate/100)/12, $i));
        $income = $income*(1+($rowage/100));
        $mpayment = $income *$paytoinc/100 ;
    }
    echo $mpayment = $income *$paytoinc/100 ;
}
?>
```

I have 2 periods , 1 is included in the other
for some reason this is making endless loop , I'm new so can anyone  tell me what am I missing and doing wrong ?

Comment: So as well as the correct answer below by @bart-friederichs there is a reasonable amount of redundancy in the code. You are evaluating `$mpayment` on each iteration of the inner loop but only using the final value that you calculate in the last line of your outer loop. You could remove this line from the inner loop to increase efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are make a mistake here:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $graduation ; $i=+12) {
```

`$i=+12` will assign `12` to `$i`. Change to:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $graduation ; $i+=12) {
```

That being said, learn how to debug. This bug would come up quite quickly if you `echo`'d `$i` in the innermost loop.

Comment: thanks lots :3 sorry for making you answer for something really stupid xD